# File not found error 2 в SublimeREPL Python

Tags: python, sublime-text-3

При попытке открыть `python` в `SublimeREPL` возникла ошибка:

> file not found error 2

Я знаю что как-то связано с путем (посмотрел на английском сайте), но не могли бы вы объяснить конкретнее что надо делать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на ютубе
следуйте по следующей ссылке:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM2LbXCkLDI